# UIPickerView with one object

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I am using a UIPickerView and currently their is only a single object in it. How can I display that single object on label.
It has this weird property that when we use pickerView the data is not set selected by default.Once we choose another object or roll it, then only any particular object is selected. Hence if only one object is their in pickerView. It does not count as selected even though when you tap on that single object.
I tried a lot but found that if their are more than one object then only you can display the selected object on label but not if their is only one object.

Comment: Still waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a code that is triggered when the UIPickerView changes, like this:

```
#pragma

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
//Action that triggers following code: 
{
NSString *nameString = [nameOnMutubaleArrayYouWannaGetDataFrom objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]]; //Or 1 if u have multiple rows

NSString *labelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                          @" %@ ", nameString];

labelOutput.text = labelString;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And you will need to connect the #pragma delegate to the pickerview in XIB

Comment: When we use pickerView the data is not set selected by default.Once we choose another object or roll it, then only any particular object is selected. Hence if only one object is their in pickerView. It does not count as selected even though when you tap on object.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to say, as either you or I have learned different versions of this language. What you are saying at the moment is not making very much sense to me, can you please try to clearify and maybe add some code samples of what you have tried?

Comment: If you are asking on how to implement data to your wheel as well as getting it outputted, take a look at this. http://pastebin.com/YpfjSJKB
This is a project of mine. You need to connect both delegates to files owner in XIB.

Comment: I am just trying to say is take a picker view and put only one object inside it for display and then make that object appear on the label on selection. You will not be able to do that.